# Set file type dynamically when click on exporting menu in highcharts using chart.exportChart function

Tags: highcharts

I want to set filetype according to click on export menu on the right in the given url. For example if click on pdf then filetype should be set as application/pdf.
                        var defaultTitle = "Kalar";
                        var drilldownTitle = "";
                        var ydrillupTitle = "# of Kalar";
                        var ydrilldownTitle = "";

```
                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                        chart: {
                            type: 'column',
                            renderTo: 'upendra',
                            events: {
                                drilldown: function(e) {
                                    chart.setTitle({ text: drilldownTitle + e.point.title });
                                    chart.yAxis[0].axisTitle.attr({
                                        text: ydrilldownTitle
                                    });
                                },
                                drillup: function(e) {
                                    chart.setTitle({ text: defaultTitle });
                                    chart.yAxis[0].axisTitle.attr({
                                        text: ydrillupTitle
                                    });
                                },
                                click: function(e) {
                                    chart.exportChart({
                                        filename: chart.options.title.text
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        },

                        title: {
                            text: defaultTitle
                        },

                        subtitle: {
                            text: ''
                        },

                        credits: {
                            enabled: false
                        },

                        xAxis: {
                            categories: ['one', 'two']
                        },

                        yAxis: {
                            allowDecimals: false,
                            min: 0,
                            title: {
                                text: ydrillupTitle
                            }
                        },

                        plotOptions: {
                            column: {
                                stacking: 'normal',
                                showInLegend: true
                            }
                        },

                        series:[
                            {
                                name:'A', 
                                color:'#E9ECEE',
                                tooltip: {
                                    headerFormat: '',
                                    pointFormat: '{point.name}:<br/><b>{point.y}</b> Bookings (<b>{point.percentage:, .1f} %</b>)<br/>'
                                },
                                data:[
                                        {
                                            name: "A", 
                                            title: "A by Company",
                                            x:0, y:2
                                        }, {
                                            name: "", 
                                            x:1, y:0
                                        }
                                    ]
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Arrived', 
                                color:'#B3E5C4', 
                                tooltip: {
                                    headerFormat: '',
                                    pointFormat: '{point.name}:<br/><b>{point.y}</b> Bookings (<b>{point.percentage:, .1f} %</b>)<br/>'
                                },
                                data:[
                                        {
                                            name: "Arrived", 
                                            title: "Planned Bookings by Goods Type",
                                            x:0, y:10
                                        }, {
                                            name: "", 
                                            x:1, y:0
                                        }
                                    ]
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Unscheduled', 
                                color:'#A9ABAD', 
                                tooltip: {
                                    headerFormat: '',
                                    pointFormat: '{point.name}:<br/><b>{point.y}</b> Deliveries (<b>{point.percentage:, .1f} %</b>)<br/>'
                                },
                                data:[
                                        {
                                            name: "", 
                                            x:0, y:0
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            name: "Unscheduled", 
                                            title: "Unscheduled Deliveries by Company",
                                            x:1, y:8
                                        }
                                    ]
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Rejected', 
                                color:'#FF838F', 
                                tooltip: {
                                    headerFormat: '',
                                    pointFormat: '{point.name}:<br/><b>{point.y}</b> Deliveries (<b>{point.percentage:, .1f} %</b>)<br/>'
                                },
                                data:[
                                        {
                                            name: "", 
                                            x:0, y:0
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            name: "Rejected", 
                                            title: "Rejected Deliveries Reasons",
                                            x:1, y:7
                                        }
                                    ]
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Complete', 
                                color:'#B3E5C4', 
                                tooltip: {
                                    headerFormat: '',
                                    pointFormat: '{point.name}:<br/><b>{point.y}</b> Deliveries (<b>{point.percentage:, .1f} %</b>)<br/>'
                                },
                                data:[
                                        {
                                            name: "", 
                                            x:0, y:0
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            name: "Complete", 
                                            title: "Actual Deliveries by Goods Type",
                                            x:1, y:6
                                        }
                                    ]
                            }
                        ]
                    });    
            });
```

Comment: This is a little bit unclear, because defulty when you click on exported item, then proper type is set. So could you supply me a details, what is wrong with that?

Comment: Hi @SebastianBochan simply we use exporting: { filename: "Demo" }, but i want to set that thing in drill down and drill up function that i have done in above source code.
But the problem is when i am exporting chart it is exportable in only png format whether option is clicked in export menu. So i want this title should be concetenate with all formats and all formats should be downloadable.

Comment: Simply when i export chart in any format it should be exported with the its title not with the default

Comment: Any luck with how to save the exported file with title dynamically.

Comment: In your piece of code there is no drilldown. Could you update your code: http://jsfiddle.net/bmp6Leh5/ with end-code ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan I have updated code with drilldown data. this is the url  : http://jsfiddle.net/upendrasharma221/bmp6Leh5/2/ .

Comment: When we click on drill down title will be changed so each time we export the chart, it should be export with the current title in filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit menuItems in exporting options and then set filename, extracting that information from title.

```
exporting: {
                        buttons: {
                            contextButton: {
                                menuItems: [{
                                    textKey: 'printChart',
                                    onclick: function () {
                                        this.print();
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    separator: true
                                }, {
                                    textKey: 'downloadPNG',
                                    onclick: function () {

                                        var title = this.title.textStr;

                                        this.exportChart({
                                            type: 'image/png',
                                            filename: title
                                        });
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    textKey: 'downloadJPEG',
                                    onclick: function () {
                                        var title = this.title.textStr;
                                        this.exportChart({
                                            type: 'image/jpeg',
                                            filename: title
                                        });
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    textKey: 'downloadPDF',
                                    onclick: function () {
                                        var title = this.title.textStr;
                                        this.exportChart({
                                            type: 'application/pdf',
                                            filename: title
                                        });
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    textKey: 'downloadSVG',
                                    onclick: function () {
                                         var title = this.title.textStr;
                                        this.exportChart({
                                            type: 'image/svg+xml',
                                            filename: title
                                        });
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bmp6Leh5/4/

Comment: Sounds great, for future, please attach better description and include proper demo. Then you will achieve correct answers, faster ;)